# How to validate certificate in soap service in php?

Tags: php, soap, certificate

We are sending certificate to soap service using following code

```
$wsdl = "https://localhost/MyService/myservices.php?wsdl";
$local_cert = "C:\\SoapCerts\ClientKeyAndCer.pem";
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('local_cert' => $local_cert));
$theResponse = $soapClient->test();
```

But there is no reference to validate that certificate in service. I just want to know how to validate the correct certificate in service code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put both private key and public key at the same PEM file. Something like this in linux:

```
# cat publicKey.pem privateKey.pem > key.pem
```

So, check if the path to your PEM file is correct (escaping slashes):

```
$local_cert = "C:\\SoapCerts\\ClientKeyAndCer.pem";
```

Comment: We need to validate the certificate in server side (service). We are sure our file path correct.

Comment: Hey, happy new year! I found a step-by-step that may help you...

[Creating a PHP Soap Request with a certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147988/creating-a-php-soap-request-with-a-certificate)