# PHP: certificate chain for SOAP request

Tags: php, web-services, soap, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I have sample SOAP request message like below,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v="http://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/ws/ds/common/v_1_0">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<v:DITWSAuthInfoEle>
<v:userID>xxxxxxxxxx</v:userID>
<v:password>xxxxxxxxxx</v:password>
<v:certChain>xxxxxxxxxx</v:certChain>
<v:signature>xxxxxxxxxx</v:signature>
</v:DITWSAuthInfoEle>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I got the  authentication details and xyz.pfx file. By using this file I have got the XML signature representation and added that to the SOAP request. Here my question is how do I acquire certChain (Certificate Chain) and how to add that to the SOAP request. Any one can help me on this?

Comment: If you found an answer to be helpful, remember to upvote it. And remember to "check" / select the answer that best answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using [SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php), the server certificate is validated by default and you can send a client certificate like this:

```
$protected_url = "https://my-server/?wsdl";
$my_cert_file = "/my/path/to/mycert.pem";

$client = new SoapClient($protected_url, array('local_cert', $my_cert_file) );
```

Or, if your certfificate requires a passphrase:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://url.to.service/", array(
        'local_cert' => 'client_certificate.pem', 'passphrase' => 'PASSPHRASE',
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
));
```

Then, if you want to see the xml, you can use [__getLastRequest](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php)

Check also this detailed answer on how to use SOAP with certificates on PHP:

[Creating a PHP SOAP request with a certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147988/creating-a-php-soap-request-with-a-certificate)

Comment: Hello elcodedocle thanks for your reply. So you are saying that; have to locate .pem file while create new SOAP client. So here are the another set of questions,
How can I get the .pem file certificate? I have .pfx file only.
What are the params; "certChain" and "signature" (which is in the sample XML request that provided in question) referring to and how can I get it? 

Kindly any one can help me on this?

Comment: Try openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem

Comment: Or openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -clcerts -nodes -out certandkeysunprotected.pem if you want the keys too (-nodes removes the passphrase protection, I believe)

Comment: Thanks elcodedocle for your kind help. What I am seeking is; what is the "certChain" and "signature" referring to? What type of input I need to provide for that params? How that params type will be? After studying the webservice providers doc; I understood that; "signature" param must be the [XML Signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature). So what data/datatype for "certChain" (Certificate Chain) param?

Comment: The cert chain is the chain of trust from the authority signing your certificate to a root authority that is trusted by both parts. Each authority signs the authority below, generating extra certificates up to the root authority. The certificates on the certification path are usually bundled togheter on a chain. For example: https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1203&nav=0,1,95 (this is how they are bundled on apache and openssl)

Comment: If you want more info, check the wikipedia article on X.509: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509 or comodo knowledge base SSL articles: https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=view&parentcategoryid=1&nav=0

Comment: (but you shouldn't need to worry about it if you intend to use the SoapClient class. Just point to a properly formatted .pem file and it will be fine, the XML will be automatically generated and you'll be able to see it using __getLastRequest)

Comment: Regarding the signature: It's not the XML signature. `<v:signature>xxxxxxxxxx</v:signature>` field contains the X.509 certificate signature: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Structure_of_a_certificate