# How to encrypt each soap request in php

Tags: php, encryption, soap, wss

I'm unable to make an encrypted SOAP request in PHP.  As per the documentation, I encrypted each request to the payment gateway. I generated a CSR & sent it to the authority for the certificate. They sent back me the domain certificate & CA certificate. The biggest problem is that the documentation is not meant for PHP. As per the document:

> The web service is protected with WS-Security Sign and encryption
>   policy

After searching a long time I found a [helper class from Git](https://github.com/course-hero/wse-php/blob/master/examples/soap-sign-encrypt.php) but whenever I try to connect I get the following error:

*General security error (No certificates were found for decryption (KeyId))*

> **FaultCode :** wsse:InvalidSecurity

I tried to set SSL header as follows:

```
$contextOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer'   => false,
        'verify_peer_name'  => false,
        'cafile'        => '../../certs/CA.cer',
        'local_cert'        => '../../certs/server.cer',
        'local_pk'        => '../../certs/private_key.key',
        'verify_depth'  => 0,
        'allow_self_signed'=>true,
    )
);

$sslContext = stream_context_create($contextOptions);
```

**Update**

I defined the keys as :

```
define('PRIVATE_KEY', 'server_prvate_key.key');
define('CERT_FILE', 'domain_cert.cer');
define('SERVICE_CERT', 'CA.cer');
```

Anything wrong with this definition (please see the above GIT link)?

Comment: Do that `cer`/`key` files/path exists? Did you take a look on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147988/creating-a-php-soap-request-with-a-certificate

Comment: @GabrielHeming Yes. The files exist

Comment: You need to define the full path to your key and certificates, that helper class won't guess in what folder they are

Comment: @Capsule The path is correct , The key & certificates contents are available too

Comment: Where do you exactly implement the class you refer to?

Comment: @stevenvanc i used the class exactly as shown in the link.i really dont need to use that class if there is an alternate way , but i don't have gud knowledge in soap.

Comment: I meant: Can you show more code? I don't see where you call or implement that class in your code?

Comment: No changes, directly added private key , & certificates. 
I added the above $contextOptions as : 
$sc = new MySoap($wsdl, array('trace' => 1,'stream_context' => $sslContext));

Answer (score 6):

Are you tried using curl?

Use the following option to set your certificate:

```
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'CA.cer' );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERT, 'domain_cert.cer' );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLKEY, 'server_prvate_key.key' );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'certificate_password' ); //if have
```

I use encrypted connection to payment gateways and other services using curl and works like a charm.

Comment: I tried curl But im getting false after curl execution , after checking the exception i found the error : " wsse:InvalidSecurityMissing wsse:Security header in request", I dont know how to add the security header ! searched  a while & i found some samples with suername and passwords